# Unranking pseudo-random values to produce uniform distribution over all permutations

Tags: combinatorics, modular-arithmetic, random

Following [this question (and answers) on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28990820/iterator-to-produce-unique-random-order).

The problem is to find a method to produce an unranking of combinatorial objects in random order, but in such a way that all possible orderings are unformly and unbiasedly sampled.

> In my answer it was mentioned that a scheme similar to the generation
>   of pseudo-random numbers will work, but now the new question is under
>   what values of the modulo function will be able to sample uniformaly
>   and unbiased all the orderings?

Specificaly it was mentioned that a scheme like:

```
def succ(index, numItems):
   return (index*seed + step) mod numItems
```

Will return such an ordering, provided that at least `seed` and `step` are relatively prime and large enough with respect to `numItems` (so the space of items is uniformly sampled without periodicities)

However for what values of `seed` and `step` (possibly as functions of `numItems`) will one be able to sample all possible orderings of the items in an unbiased and uniform way?? In  other words for what values of `seed` and `step` can one say that one can generate all possible orderings (uniquely and unbiasedly) and not just one of them?

**Note** this is mostly a mathematical question than algorithmic one per se. We dont mind if the ordering function can be reversed engineered, only that we can generate succesor functions with modulo (for fast performance) which for **specific** values of `seed` and `step` we can generate any random ordering of the indices unbiasedly.  Is this possible or are there orderings which cannot be given this way?

Comment: Would it be sufficient to generate a uniformly random permutation of numItems number of elements?  I.e. if you knew the index of the item, would that be sufficient (to either look it up or create it).  If so, I can describe a nice algorithm for generating uniformly random permutations in linear time (with very small constant).

Comment: @TravisJ, yes as mentioned in SO, the iterator is supposed to be able to unrank the combinatorial object by its index, only the ordering of indices is needed here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a really nice algorithm of Myrvold and Rusky to rank/unrank permutations in linear time.  You can download the (very short) paper here: http://webhome.cs.uvic.ca/~ruskey/Publications/RankPerm/RankPerm.html

Essentially, the algorithm is derived from the method of generating a random permutation.  Start with the identity, then randomly swap the first element with one of the later elements.  Next, randomly swap the second element with one of the later; then swap the third with one of the later, etc.  "One of the later" could include swapping with itself (i.e. make no swap).  Their algorithm gives a way of taking an integer (the permutation number) and making a specified sequence of swaps (based on the number) to get that random permutation.  Likewise, from a given permutation, you can unravel the swaps to generate it's index.  It is a very fast algorithm.

EDIT:  The way I envision selecting your objects in random order is this.  I assume you have $n$ objects and for each $1\leq i\leq n$ you can either look up object $i$ on a list (memory intensive) or regenerate the object.  Then, you use a pseudo-random number generator to pick a random number $r$ between $1$ and $n!$.  This is your permutation number which you unrank to get permutation number $r$, call it $\sigma$ (this will be viewed as a random ordering of your objects).  Then you take your object in the order $\sigma(1), \sigma(2), \sigma(3),...,\sigma(n)$.  Where, again, I assume you can look-up or generate object $\sigma(i)$ as needed.

EDIT, EDIT: In the case that you want to use the linear function $f(i)=i*seed+step \mod n$ (where $n$ is the number of items), if seed is relatively prime to $n$ (their gcd is 1) then you will not get get duplicate values out of $f$ until you've entered more than $n$ values for $i$.  The reason is the following:  suppose that $f(i_1)=f(i_2)$, then

\begin{align*}
i_{1} seed + step &\equiv i_{2} seed + step \mod n \\
i_{1} seed &\equiv i_{2} seed \mod n \\
\end{align*}

Since $\text{gcd}(n, seed)=1$ it follows that $seed$ has an inverse modulo $n$, i.e. a value $seed^{-1}$ so that $seed^{-1}\cdot seed\equiv seed\cdot seed^{-1}\equiv 1 \mod n$.  Multiplying the above by $seed^{-1}$ we have:

\begin{align*}
i_{1}seed\cdot seed^{-1} \equiv i_{2}seed\cdot seed^{-1} \mod {n} \\
i_{1} \equiv i_{2} \mod {n}.
\end{align*}

Thus, you only get repeats out of $f$ is the two inputs are congruent modulo $n$.  To avoid this, just take the integers $0, 1, 2, ..., n-1$ as your inputs to $f$.  Note that if $\text{gcd}(seed, n)\neq 1$ then $seed$ does not have an inverse and the argument fails.

Comment: +1 for the reference of the algorithm, but can you say how this is applied to this specific question? i'm not sure i follow

Comment: @NikosM. I made an edit to the post to try to clarify this.  I hope it helps.

Comment: @NikosM. If you fish around on google a bit, there are many optimized implementations of the algorithm out there (I've used some in C before).  It is not so hard to code up on your own though if you want.

Comment: It answers the original question on SO (and it is good if you would like to post it there as well), but how about the modulo function and the values of seed and step, is this mentioned in the paper (did not read it yet)?

Comment: @NikosM., the function you described above will give you all the elements (in some order) exactly once provided that seed is relatively prime to numItems.  What will happen though is that you won't see your elements really "shuffled."  You might try a few experiments with this, but what you'll see is that you get an arithmetic progression of you indices (dictated by seed) and then after it wraps, you'll get another arithmetic progression (shifted from the first but with the same common difference).  So, the elements are not very random.  This may or may not be a problem for your application.

Comment: hmm, can this be fixed for specific values of seed and step, or is it lost case (which i dont think so)? Of course the ordering stops when numItems have been generated. Then another ordering starts (if one wants a new one). This is mostly a mathematical question and not an algorithmic one (which has been answered by the answres there and this one)

Comment: @NikosM., what I was trying to say, is that if you use your scheme above, once I've seen 2 consecutive elements from the sequence, I can uniquely determine all the rest.  It isn't a matter of the seed or step (or numItems), it is because you're using a linear function.  If you used a higher order polynomial (that was still one-to-one) it would take longer (the degree $+1$ number of consecutive items) before it is determined.

Comment: we dont mind if the ordering function can be reversed engineered, only that we can generate succesor functions with modulo (for fast performance) which for **specific** values of `seed` and `step` we can generate any random ordering of the indices unbiasedly

Comment: @NikosM. The determinism (in that you can reconstruct the future elements because you know the last few) means that the sequence is heavily biased (in a probabilistic sense, it is strictly determined).

Comment: @NikosM., the algorithm in the paper actually uses fewer operations that your linear function mod $n$.  It uses (for each element) a single modular reduction and a single integer division.  Whereas your proposed algorithm uses an integer multiplication, and integer addition, and a modular reduction.

Comment: yeap the algorithm is good and i will probably use it (i build a combinatorics library, Abacus on github), but this is another question mostly mathematical asking for which values of `seed` and `step` (or range of values) can one say that any ordering can be generated unbiasedly

Comment: @NikosM., depending on what precisely you mean by unbiasedly, there would be no values of seed and step.  If you only mean that you don't get repeats (until you've seen everything once), then any value of step works and any value of seed that is relatively prime to numItems.

Comment: unbiasedly means (as mentioned in question) that all possible orderings can be given for certain (different) valus of seed and step. is this possible or are there orderings which cannot be given this way? this is the question regarding pseudo-numbers and modular arithmetic

Comment: @NikosM., in that case, it will always do what you want provided that seed is relatively prime to numItems.  I personally wouldn't call this unbiased, I'd call it one-to-one.

Comment: if you can justify this (bonus if an algorithm is given for calculating the values) i can accept the answer

Comment: @NikosM., the edit has been made, let me know if it is clear.

Comment: thanks, it is clear, but still not what is asked, let me help. Of course if (some) values of seed and step are relatively prime one gets indeed a (pseudo-)random ordering. The question is if there is an equivalence class of values of (seed, step) such as every ordering can be obtained (not just some of them, this is known). i'm talking about equivalence classes since multiple different values of seed/step can result in same ordering. if this can be justified i can accept it

Comment: @NikosM., your function cannot give you every ordering because there are only $n$ choices of $seed$ and $n$ choices of $step$, so only $n^2$ possible orderings that can be generated with your method.  There are $n!$ total orderings of the points.  Since $n!>n^2$ when $n\geq 4$ you cannot get every ordering.  If you want every ordering, you'll have to use a method like the one I described.  Also, your step could be any value (doesn't matter how it is related to seed or numItems.  But, you must choose seed to be relatively prime to numItems--so you really have fewer than $n$ choices of seed.

Comment: why is that, i dont agree why only $n^2$ values of seed/step since every relatively prime number can do, plus the values fo step (except zero of course), if you couple these in equivalence classes (for those that result in exactly same ordering), these classes should be way more than $n^2$

Comment: i think this question is not so trivial, but i might be wrong

Comment: after considering specific examples of permutations and a lineasr mapping, it seems there are permutations which cannot be generated by just a linear mapping, one would need a polynomial mapping with more free parameters to adjust so all permutations/orderings can be represented. Accepting the answer and posting new question about permutations as polynomial mappings

Comment: something like this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_polynomial